# Having sensitive content for github pages public repo

Tags: security, github, github-pages, webhooks, privacy

I'm making a website and I have a slack webhook I'm using to post messages to a slack channel. I tried pushing to github (on a public repo since I have the free version and you can't have a private repo with github pages for free) but I got an email from slack saying the link was compromised and it got changed.

After doing some research I tried putting the new link in a config file which I added to my `.gitignore` file so it never got pushed to github, but after I ran `npm run deploy` to build the website the URL was still visible on the repo (I'm not exactly sure why but I assume since I'm doing a `POST` request to it). I was wondering if there is any way for me to get around this issue?

Comment: Do you have previous commits showing that link? Because previous commits can still be visible.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case since they invalidated the previous, visible, link